# photoshop - scripts - export - layers to files MISSING

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4, layers

I am using Photoshop CS4 on a Mac Powerbook - 
I am missing the ability to export layers as files by
going to scripts -  export -  layers to files .
Does any one know where to get this plugin(?)
exactly -

Answer (score 0):

it's a javascript action by Adobe and it's installed by default in my CS4. Here:
`/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Presets/Scripts/Export Layers To Files.jsx`